# StackoverflowException while in prod on IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, iis, production

I have a serious issue trying to put my Web Application into production.

My application is coded in VB.Net (With Visual Web Developer 2010), and the environment of production is a virtual machine with Microsoft Server 2008 R2, and IIS 7.5, the application is running with Asp.net 4.0. I tried also on my own computer (Windows 7), where I installed IIS, and the same bug occurs.

To limit the charge on SQL server, I put into session a list of rights, which is loaded each time the user wants to have access to any page.

The bug occurs exactly when this list contains more than 178 objects. At 178, the session is created and the page is correctly executed ; but when I add a 179th element or more (and I tried with different elements, so this can't come from the elements themselves), the page just don't execute correctly the code and IIS crash...

It seems that when there is more than 179 elements in this list, IIS just recycle the App, and so, the session is lost...

When I debug the application with Visual Web Developer, it is running well, without bug. But when I try to put it into production, that bug occurs. So, this seems to be linked with IIS.

Another problem is that when IIS recycle my App, it doesn't create any log file. So I have nothing more precise to give you.

I need help to find a solution to this problem. I try for a week, and I found nothing... this is driving me crazy... If someone has any idea or need more information, please tell me, so I can dig deeper...

Thanks to everyone.

**EDIT :**

I tried something else, I bypassed the sessions, and now, the rights are directly charged from SQL. The problem still occurs. So, it doesn't come from sessions, but SQL.
So, I wonder if there is any limit while doing requests on SQL.

But SQL doesn't seems to have any problem with request that return 3000 elements, and when it returns 179 elements with a lot of joins, it just crash... Well, I have no idea what to do or where search for a solution...

**EDIT2 :**
But, like I said, the problem doesn't occurs when I try execute the code from Visual Web developer. And, with it or in production environment, it's the same SQL server that execute de SQL requests... So, the problem can't come from SQL finally...

**EDIT3 :**
I finally found something. In the Windows logs, I have a StackOverflowException... What happy news ! (And we are on stackoverflow.com, is that linked? xD).

**EDIT4 :**
Here is the error from the windows log. Maybe it can help anyone.

```
Nom du journal :Application
Source :       Windows Error Reporting
Date :         29/04/2014 11:53:11
ID de l’événement :1001
Catégorie de la tâche :Aucun
Niveau :       Information
Mots clés :    Classique
Utilisateur :  N/A
Ordinateur :   SRVWEB.DOMMH01.local
Description :
Récipient d’erreurs , type 0
Nom d’événement : CLR20r3
Réponse : Non disponible
ID de CAB : 0

Signature du problème : 
P1 : w3wp.exe
P2 : 7.5.7601.17514
P3 : 4ce7afa2
P4 : System.Core
P5 : 4.0.30319.18408
P6 : 5231116c
P7 : 1197
P8 : 0
P9 : System.StackOverflowException
P10 : 

Fichiers joints :

Ces fichiers sont peut-être disponibles ici :
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_e41148f8d4e7fcf353a2d93bfe4367a48b981de2_0a6131b2

Symbole d’analyse : 
Nouvelle recherche de la solution : 0
ID de rapport : 125b520d-cf84-11e3-912f-00155dc81602
Statut du rapport : 4
```

**EDIT 5 :**
I put here the piece of code where I take the rights with LINQ to SQL. I don't think this will be really helpful, but there it is...

A right contains a Username, the id of the rights, the id of a family (a family is a set of "objects"), and a place. So finnaly, I get a list of "Object/Place" associated with rights for a specified user... So I can limit the access for only some "object/place" for each user. 
Another thing is the familyJoker, and the placeJoker. When a right is associated with a placeJoker, wee add to the rights of this user any object/place where the object is in the family. It's the same when the family is the familyJoker. Finally, if family and place are both joker, we add all the combinations possible(the combinations possible are in the objectPlace table)

This is the code :

```
Public Shared Function getListeDroitsUtilisateurSession(ByVal username As String) As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession)

    Dim db As SINDIDB = New SINDIDB
    Dim familleJoker As String = FamilleMetier.famille_Joker
    Dim lieuJoker As String = Lieu.lieu_Joker
    Dim requeteSansJoker = From d In db.DroitsUtilisateurs
                                Where d.Utilisateur = username
                            Join r In db.Roles
                                On d.ID_Role Equals r.ID_Role
                            Join oif In db.ObjetsInFamilleMetiers
                                On d.ID_Famille Equals oif.ID_Famille
                            Join f In db.FamilleMetiers
                                On oif.ID_Famille Equals f.ID_Famille
                                Where (Not f.Nom_Famille = familleJoker)
                            Join ol In db.ObjetLieux
                                On oif.ID_Objet Equals ol.ID_Objet
                                Where (d.ID_Lieu = ol.ID_Lieu)
                            Join l In db.Lieux
                                On ol.ID_Lieu Equals l.ID_Lieu
                                Where (Not l.Valeur_Lieu = lieuJoker)
                            Select New DroitsUtilisateurSession With {.Role = r, .ObjetLieu = ol}

    Dim requeteFamilleJoker = From d In db.DroitsUtilisateurs
                                    Where d.Utilisateur = username
                                Join r In db.Roles
                                    On d.ID_Role Equals r.ID_Role
                                Join f In db.FamilleMetiers
                                    On d.ID_Famille Equals f.ID_Famille
                                    Where (f.Nom_Famille = familleJoker)
                                From oCross In db.Objets
                                Join ol In db.ObjetLieux
                                    On oCross.ID_Objet Equals ol.ID_Objet
                                    Where (d.ID_Lieu = ol.ID_Lieu)
                                Select New DroitsUtilisateurSession With {.Role = r, .ObjetLieu = ol}

   Dim requeteLieuJoker = From d In db.DroitsUtilisateurs
                                Where d.Utilisateur = username
                            Join r In db.Roles
                                On d.ID_Role Equals r.ID_Role
                            Join l In db.Lieux
                                On d.ID_Lieu Equals l.ID_Lieu
                                Where (l.Valeur_Lieu = lieuJoker)
                            Join oif In db.ObjetsInFamilleMetiers
                                On d.ID_Famille Equals oif.ID_Famille
                            From lCross In db.Lieux
                            Join ol In db.ObjetLieux
                                On oif.ID_Objet Equals ol.ID_Objet
                                Where (lCross.ID_Lieu = ol.ID_Lieu)
                            Select New DroitsUtilisateurSession With {.Role = r, .ObjetLieu = ol}

    Dim requeteFamilleEtLieuJoker = From d In db.DroitsUtilisateurs
                                        Where d.Utilisateur = username
                                    Join r In db.Roles
                                        On d.ID_Role Equals r.ID_Role
                                    Join f In db.FamilleMetiers
                                        On d.ID_Famille Equals f.ID_Famille
                                        Where (f.Nom_Famille = familleJoker)
                                    Join l In db.Lieux
                                        On d.ID_Lieu Equals l.ID_Lieu
                                        Where (l.Valeur_Lieu = lieuJoker)
                                    From olCross In db.ObjetLieux
                                    Select New DroitsUtilisateurSession With {.Role = r, .ObjetLieu = olCross}

    Dim requeteTotale = requeteSansJoker.Union(requeteFamilleJoker).Union(requeteLieuJoker).Union(requeteFamilleEtLieuJoker)

    Dim resultat As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession) = requeteTotale.ToList

    Dim listeDroitsUtilisateur As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession) = New List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession)

    If (resultat IsNot Nothing) Then
        For Each item In resultat
            listeDroitsUtilisateur.Add(New DroitsUtilisateurSession With {.Role = item.Role, .ObjetLieu = item.ObjetLieu})
        Next
    End If

    Return listeDroitsUtilisateur
End Function
```

**EDIT 6:** I found something about the limit size of the pile of w3wp applications. This can be linked to my problem... 
Here is the link :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932909
I'm digging.

**EDIT 7:** So, I made a little change to my code. Now, when it have to calculate the rights, it let another thread do it. This thread has a bigger stack size. So I thought it can change something, but the same problem occurs...

And I don't said it before, but there is NO recursive code in my App.

Here is the code I implemented :

```
Dim ThreadD As ThreadDroits = New ThreadDroits
ThreadD.Username = User.Identity.Name

Dim t = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadD.ExecuteDroits, 419430400)
t.Start()
t.Join()

Dim listeDroits As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession) = ThreadD.ListeDroits
```

And here is the new class :

```
Public Class ThreadDroits
    Private m_Username As String
    Public Property Username As String
        Get
            Return m_Username
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Username = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_listeDroits As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession)
    Public Property ListeDroits As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession)
        Get
            Return m_listeDroits
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of DroitsUtilisateurSession))
            m_listeDroits = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub ExecuteDroits()
        ListeDroits = DroitsUtilisateurSession.getListeDroitsUtilisateurSession(Username)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One thought - what data-structure are you using to store these objects? Is it one that enforces uniqueness, like a dictionary?

Comment: Also, have you checked in Event Viewer to see if there is an event in there that might give more details?

Comment: Finally, from a security point of view, storing a user's access rights in session isn't that great - a user can keep a session going almost indefinitely if sufficiently motivated (and if you're session server doesn't crash) so would be able to, for example, keep a right that it was intended they were only granted temporarily - you may want to revisit your design anyway (which will have the effect of making this bug moot...)

Comment: Post the code that causes the crash.

Comment: I can't put the whole code here... And furthermore, the code is executing well when I try in Debug mode... So, I think that the problem doesn't come from the code itself, but from IIS or SQL...

Comment: To preserve session state through IIS process recycling, you can use a different process to store the state, e.g. use [state server mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Andrew Morton. This session itself is not the problem. The problem is the recycling. Why IIS recycle when I log in? This is definitely not what it should do...